# PHP/MYSQLI display only the first two results ... Do not want to use a limit in the query

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 $newrow = $row['name'];
 $id = $row['id'];
 if ($id == 1000){
      echo $newrow . "</br>";
 }
}
```

I want to display only the first two results where `$id = 1000`.

I do not want to place a limit on my query as I use the results in other areas in my code and do not want to have multiple queries. Such as in another part I want to display the first two results where `$id = 1001`.

I have tried using a for statement... `for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)` however the best I can get is to have `$newrow` displayed twice for every row in the result.

Any help?

Comment: You desperately need to learn modern PHP. Such a code were in use in the last century. So please learn to use templates (this *is* an answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch all results and need to access the result set via the id value you could build up an array containing your results indexed by id like this:

```
$myResult = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $myResult[$row["id"]] = row;
}
echo $myResult[1000]["name"] . '<br/>';
echo $myResult[1001]["name"] . '<br/>';
```